# Golang: why following code snippet do not write to file?

Tags: go

I have following part of code which do not write any data to file log.txt. I don't understand why ? It should not be sync problem, because I close file before start any go routine and open/close file inside of each routine.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "runtime"
    "os"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    runtime.GOMAXPROCS(4)

    f, _ := os.Create("./log.txt")
    f.Close()

    logCh := make(chan string, 50)

    go func() {
        for {
            msg, ok := <- logCh
            if ok {
                logTime := time.Now().Format(time.RFC3339)

                f, _ := os.OpenFile("./log.txt", os.O_APPEND, os.ModeAppend)

                f.WriteString(logTime + " - " + msg)

                f.Close()

            } else {
                break
            }
        }
    }()


    for i:=1; i < 10;i++ {
        for j:=1; j<10;j++ {
            go func(i, j int) {
                msg := fmt.Sprintf("%d + %d = %d\n", i, j, i+j)
                logCh <- msg
                fmt.Print(msg)
            }(i, j)
        }
    }


    //fmt.Scanln()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

two obvious faults:

1. the main routine do not wait for other goroutines, when main routine return, the program terminate, that's why log.txt is empty. `sync.WaitGroup` maybe helpful.
2. `msg, ok := <- logCh`, `ok` is only `false` when `logCh` is closed and empty. And you are not calling `close(logCh)`.

Comment: But the file created and closed inside of main routine before any other goroutine starts and I open and close files inside of the each main routine, but files steel empty.

Comment: @PARUS what do you mean "I open and close files inside of the each main routine"?   `WriteString` will only execute if  `logCh` receive message. but before that, the main function has run over.

Comment: >> if logCh receive message. but before that, the main function has run over. Sorry, in code above you need to uncomment following //fmt.Scanln() and main function still run.

Comment: open file for writing, `os.O_WRONLY|os.O_APPEND`

Comment: Thank you - came to the same solution yesterday.

Answer (score 1):

For one, you need to wait for your channel to empty. In this case you don't need a buffered channel either. Use a `WaitGroup`

Secondly, opening and closing the file in every goroutine while ignoring the error is the actual issue. You don't need to open and close the file every time. Open once, sync after writes.

This works:

package main

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "runtime"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    runtime.GOMAXPROCS(4)

    f, _ := os.Create("./log.txt")
    defer f.Close()

    logCh := make(chan string)
    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    for i := 1; i < 10; i++ {
        for j := 1; j < 10; j++ {
            wg.Add(1)
            go func(i, j int) {
                defer wg.Done()
                msg := fmt.Sprintf("%d + %d = %d\n", i, j, i+j)
                logCh <- msg
                fmt.Print(msg)

            }(i, j)
        }
    }

    go func() {
        for {
            msg, ok := <-logCh
            if ok {
                logTime := time.Now().Format(time.RFC3339)

                f.WriteString(logTime + " - " + msg)
                f.Sync()

            } else {
                break
            }
        }
    }()

    wg.Wait()

    //fmt.Scanln()
}
```

There's also some extra info in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39776481/how-to-wait-until-buffered-channel-semaphore-is-empty)

Comment: Yes, I did this was. Not do close fine right after creation and use same fileDescriptior inside of the each goroutine to write in files. Yes - in this case it will works ever without WaitGroup. But why it does not work in initial example - files creates and close before ever any channel or goroutine start. And I open/close files inside of each goroutine. But files are still empty. Why ?

Comment: Buffered channels are non-blocking. Your main() exits faster.